# Is it able to query a objects where it's property(a list) contain certain value?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For example, I have a list like this, and I wanna search for objects which have the child "apple", is it doable?

```
[{id: 1, child:["apple", "tomato", "potato"]}, {id: 1, child:["potato"]}, ...]
```

Comment: Are those objects direct children of your root reference?

Comment: Yes, and the data is from the firebase realtime database.

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

That's just basic Javascript ... You should be able to do it yourself. Otherwise, you should learn Javascript instead of Angular.

Nevertheless, use the according tags.

And here is your answer.

```js
const apples = data.filter(item => item.child.includes('apple'));
```

Comment: I know I could load all the data and filter it out. I was wondering if there is any way to do it on the firebase side. Thanks.